# Removing images by clicking on delete button

Tags: jquery

How can I remove specific image with complete division by clicking on the respective DELETE button, below is the source code. kindly assist me on this.

```
<div class="slide"> 
   <img class="photo" src="img001.jpg"> 
   <p>image description</p> 
   <button id="del">Delete</button> 
</div> 
<div class="slide"> 
   <img src="img002.jpg"> 
   <p>image description</p> 
   <button>Delete</button> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Images don't help a lot, show us the code you have tried to create this yourself.

Comment: please use the edit question button and paste your code into the question

Comment: whole division including image,description and delete button by clicking on respective delete button.

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen and  Alive to Die--Anant singh, kindly help iam new to coding

Comment: thank you soo much  Anant sing , its working

Comment: You should have mentioned whether the images need to be deleted from the server or just in that current browser request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$('.slide button').on('click',function(){ // on click of button
  $(this).parent('.slide').remove(); // find the parent div and remove it
});
```

***Working example:-***

```js
$('.slide button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).parent('.slide').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide"> 
  <img class="photo" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/siivagunner/images/9/92/Twitter_Icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20170513181034"> 
  <p>image description</p> 
  <button id="del">Delete</button>
</div> 
<div class="slide"> 
  <img src="https://bunnymedia-8962.kxcdn.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/small_image/50x/1c9c639f71c92c9f6b86bd79f5f4d9d6/1/6/1654.7-dizzy-icon-iconbunny.jpg"> 
  <p>image description</p> 
  <button>Delete</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind a click event onto the button under the slide, and remove the slide on clicking of the button.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".slide button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">
  <img class="photo" src="img001.jpg">
  <p>image description</p>
  <button id="del">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <img src="img002.jpg">
  <p>image description</p>
  <button>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could better use .on() instead of .click()